# Получить ссылку в объекте

Tags: javascript

есть объект и тип который приходит в функцию. По примеру все поймете чего я хочу. Можно ли такое реализовать? Как правильно получить ссылку?

```js
let obj = {
  m1: [{
    message: 'Hello world!'
  }],
  m2: [],
  m3: []
}

function getElementFromObj(type) {
  this.method(type, obj.type.length >= 1)
}

function method(type, value) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'm1':
      return value ? 'post' : 'patch'
      break;
    case 'm2':
      return value ? 'post' : 'patch'
      break;
    case 'm3':
      return value ? 'post' : 'patch'
      break
    default:
      return 'post'
      break;
  }
}

console.log(getElementFromObj('m1'))
console.log(getElementFromObj('m2'))
console.log(getElementFromObj('m3'))
```

Comment: для начала `obj.type.length >= 1` поменяйте на `obj[type].length >= 1`

Comment: @Дмытрык о, спасибо!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  m1: [{
    message: 'Hello world!'
  }],
  m2: [],
  m3: []
}

function getElementFromObj(type) {
  // так как имя св-ва хранится в переменной type
  // то нужно обращаться не через точку, а через квадратные скобки
  return method(type, obj[type].length >= 1)
}

function method(type, value) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'm1':
      return value ? 'post' : 'patch'
      break;
    case 'm2':
      return value ? 'post' : 'patch'
      break;
    case 'm3':
      return value ? 'post' : 'patch'
      break
    default:
      return 'post'
      break;
  }
}

console.log(getElementFromObj('m1'))
console.log(getElementFromObj('m2'))
console.log(getElementFromObj('m3'))
```